# Angular Material Design Card Height

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am a bit new to Angular Material and how to correctly lay things out.

What I am trying to do is have an image at the top of my page that is always the size of the viewable area. Something similar to https://www.rent.com. Notice the top image is exactly the size of the viewable area, no matter if I resize the screen.

Here is what I've tried so far:

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <mat-card>
    <img mat-card-image src="../../assets/download.jpg" alt="Download image">
 </mat-card>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.container {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

This does correctly make the image the same size as the viewable area, but it does that by cutting off the bottom of the image. I would rather have the image stretch/shrink instead of just being cut off, but I am not quite sure how to achieve that.

Comment: have you set the image height as 100%? by doing this it will inherit the height of the parent component

Comment: How about using `background-image` property? Have you tried it?

Comment: @patricio, setting image height as 100% didnt work.

Comment: @abhinav - if i understand background-image, that would set the background image on the entire page, but i have other images on the page when i scroll down and i don't want the image to the the background image of the entire page.

Comment: Can you create a https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @brightwave Sorry for the late reply. Set the section height of the div and set the `background-image` property for that particular div.